# Elasticsearch should query without computing relevance (_score)

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, dsl

I'm creating filtering queries which operates on two fields. I would like to avoid computing relevance by *Elasticsearch*. How to achieve OR statement without moving to query context.

My simplified model has two boolean fields:

```
{
   is_opened,
   is_send
}
```

I'd like to prepare query with logic:

```
(is_opened == true AND is_send == true) OR (is_opened == false)
```

In other words I want to exclude documents with fields:

```
is_opened == true AND is_send == false
```

My query looks like that:

```
GET documents/default/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool":{
            "must":[
                {"term": {"is_opened":true}},
                {"term": {"is_send":true}}
              ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool":{
            "must":[
                {"term": {"is_opened":false}}
              ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Logically it works as I expected but *Elasticsearch* computes **relevance**.
I don't need it because at the end I sort results by another field so it's a place to optimize queries.
I ask about it because [Frequently used filters will be cached automatically by Elasticsearch, to speed up performance.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-filter-context.html)

My results have *_score* field computed so I think that above query is executed in query context so Elasticsearch won't cache it automatically.

In the future I would like to create queries which operates on *status* fields, where logic would be more complicated. Still I need to know how to block computing *_score*.

I noticed that changing *should* to *filter* block computing *_score* but works as *must* operator. Is it possible to change *filter* behavior?

Is it possible to use another query than should?
How to force *Elasticserach* to stop computing *_score*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrap your query inside the [`constant_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html):

```
GET documents/default/_search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "is_opened": true
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "is_send": true
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "is_opened": false
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use it but my syntax was wrong. Thanks!